# Does NTP daemon set the host timezone?

Tags: linux, ntp, daemon, ntpd

If I am using NTP daemon or ntpdate command, do I need to worry about changing the timezone?

Should I re-configure the timezone using cron job to guarantee the accuracy of the server time?

I am using ubuntu server.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You only need to set the time zone once:

```
tzselect
```

or

```
dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

NTP does not handle time zones.  All time data handled by NTP is in UTC; your local time zone setting determines the offset from there.

Answer (score 3):

If your timezone is correctly set then you need to do nothing. To check your timezone have a look at the contents of the `/etc/timezone` file.

`cat /etc/timezone`

`Europe/london`

Which is correct for my system.

If your timezone is incorrect then use

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`

to select and set your timezone. Once that is done you should be good till you move the system to another timezone (if ever).

The NTP Daemon does not set the timezone.